# $r$-Permutations of $n$ things of $k_1,...,k_j$ kinds.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, generating-functions

Given a multiset $\mathcal{M} := \{0^1,\ldots, 0^7,1^1,\ldots, 1^7, \cdots,9^1,\ldots, 9^7  \}$. i.e $10$ digits from $0$ to $9$, each present $7$ times such that $| \mathcal{M}| = 70$.

I want to count the number of $7$-Permutations of $\mathcal{M}$ such that any two permutations are indistinguishable, if they only differ by some exchange between digits of the same kind, for example $0^1 \ 1357 \ 0^6 \ 9$ and $0^6 \ 1357  \ 0^1 \ 9$ are just the same permutation $0135709$.

I tried using generating functions such that $$\bigg(1+t+\frac{t^2}{2!}+\frac{t^3}{3!}+\frac{t^4}{4!}+\frac{t^5}{5!}+\frac{t^6}{6!}+\frac{t^7}{7!}\bigg)^{10} = \sum_{r = 0}^{70} P(70,r) \ \frac{t^r}{r!}$$

After expanding, the coefficient of $t^7$ on the left is $\frac{125000}{63}$, so we get $P(70,r) = 7! \cdot \frac{125000}{63} = 10 \cdot 10^6$.

Did I count correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did indeed count correctly, and there is an easy check of the result $10^7$. Each seven-digit number, allowing leading zeroes, corresponds to a unique $7$-permutation of $\mathscr{M}$ when you don’t distinguish digits of the same type, and of course each such $7$-permutation of $\mathscr{M}$ corresponds to a unique seven-digit number when leading zeroes are allowed. There are $10^7$ seven-digit numbers, so there must be $10^7$ $7$-permutations of $\mathscr{M}$ when digits of the same type are not distinguished.

Comment: Thanks! that's true, I wanted to also make sure I am using generating functions correctly.

Comment: @9Sp: You’re welcome! And yes, the use of the generating function is fine.

Comment: Can anyone explain what is the meaning of generating that function. What that function is trying to say how we are getting answer from it?

Comment: @SMSheikh: That’s much too large a question to be answered in a comment, and it’s arguably too general for MSE at all. It can easily be the subject of an entire course. You could try starting with [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function), but something like Chapter 3 of Miklós Bóna, *Introduction to Enumerative Combinatorics*, (or any other good book on combinatorics) is likely to be a lot more helpful.